# Python : Extract icon from an .exe file

Tags: python, icons, exe

I am making a Launcher, I want to get the icon of the exe file to show it in my programs. But I don't know how to do that. I have been searching for several days for a solution.

I tried icoextract : https://github.com/jlu5/icoextract but i don't understand how it works.